# How to get RGB value from hexadecimal color code in java

Tags: java, android, colors

I have a decimal color code (eg: `4898901`). I am converting it into a hexadecimal equivalent of that as `4ac055`. How to get the red, green and blue component value from the hexadecimal color code?

Comment: You need to get 3 int from a string? Or 3 strings from a string?

Comment: i want 3 integer values of red,green and blue from my hexa decimal color code.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Assuming this is a string:

```
// edited to support big numbers bigger than 0x80000000
int color = (int)Long.parseLong(myColorString, 16);
int r = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
int g = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
int b = (color >> 0) & 0xFF;
```

Comment: I used this code in my app and when run that on android 2.3 I get excaption for myColorString: "unable to parse '4282291905' as integer". Could you tell why?

Comment: @ProSoft - the code above will not fit for you, as the number 4282291905 overflows integer boundaries. You can use Long instead (I will fix the answer)

Answer (score 9):

If you have a string this way is a lot nicer:

```
Color color =  Color.decode("0xFF0000");
int red = color.getRed();
int blue = color.getBlue();
int green = color.getGreen();
```

If you have a number then do it this way:

```
Color color = new Color(0xFF0000);
```

Then of course to get the colours you just do:

```
float red = color.getRed();
float green = color.getGreen();
float blue = color.getBlue();
```

Comment: I cannot find this class in `Android` - `android.graphics.Color` holds no such methods.

Comment: It's been a while since I played around with this code. I believe this was using the standard Java Color class.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html

Answer (score 7):

Try this,

```
colorStr e.g. "#FFFFFF"

public static Color hex2Rgb(String colorStr) {
    return new Color(
            Integer.valueOf( colorStr.substring( 1, 3 ), 16 ),
            Integer.valueOf( colorStr.substring( 3, 5 ), 16 ),
            Integer.valueOf( colorStr.substring( 5, 7 ), 16 ) );
}
```

For using Color class you have to use [java-rt-jar-stubs-1.5.0.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavartjarstubs150jar.htm) as Color class is from `java.awt.Color`

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure about your exact need. However some tips.

[Integer class can transform a decimal number to its hexadecimal representation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString%28int%29) with the method:

```
Integer.toHexString(yourNumber);
```

To get the RGB you can use the class Color:

```
Color color = new Color(4898901);
float r = color.getRed();
float g = color.getGreen();
float b = color.getBlue();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String hex1 = "#FF00FF00";    //BLUE with Alpha value = #AARRGGBB

int a = Integer.valueOf( hex1.substring( 1, 3 ), 16 );
int r = Integer.valueOf( hex1.substring( 3, 5 ), 16 );
int g = Integer.valueOf( hex1.substring( 5, 7 ), 16 );
int b = Integer.parseInt( hex1.substring( 7, 9 ), 16 );

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ARGB: " + a + " , " + r + " ,  "+ g + " , "+ b , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

String hex1 = "#FF0000";    //RED with NO Alpha = #RRGGBB

int r = Integer.valueOf( hex1.substring( 1, 3 ), 16 );
int g = Integer.valueOf( hex1.substring( 3, 5 ), 16 );
int b = Integer.parseInt( hex1.substring( 5, 7 ), 16 );

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "RGB: " + r + " ,  "+ g + " , "+ b , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have the `hex-code : 4ac055`. The first two letters are the color red. The next two are green and the two latest letters are for the color blue. So When you have the hex-code of the color red you must convert it to dez back. In these example where `red 4a = 74`. `Green c0 = 192` and `blue = 85`..

Try to make a function which split the `hexcode` and then give back the `rgb` code

Answer (score 1):

```
int color = Color.parseColor("#519c3f");

int red = Color.red(color);
int green = Color.green(color);
int blue = Color.blue(color);
```