# How to Convert colors from Hex to RGB

Tags: android, colors

I have color in the String.xml file like this  `<color name="ItemColor1">#ffff992b</color>`
how can i convert is into four variables

```
float Red;
float Green;
float Blue;
float Alfa;
```

in Java Code? any one can help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Edit:**
This was accepted as the answer but have a look at [@johann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23793064/1341412) too, it will leave you and those reading your code less confused.

If you want to learn about the underlying representation of colours, you could start [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color).

**Original answer:**

[`getColor()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor(int)) gives you the colour as an ARGB `int`.

```
int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.ItemColor1);
float red   = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
float green = (color >> 8)  & 0xFF;
float blue  = (color)       & 0xFF;
float alpha = (color >> 24) & 0xFF;
```

Comment: in blue `(color >> 0)` can be replaced with `(color)`

Answer (score 18):

You could also use the [red, green, blue] function of the Color class:

```
    int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.youcolor);
    int r = Color.red(color);
    int g = Color.green(color);
    int b = Color.blue(color);
```

Answer (score 4):

Please take a look

[How to get RGB value from hexadecimal color code in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427141/how-to-get-rgb-value-from-hexadecimal-color-code-in-java)

```
int color = Integer.parseInt(myColorString, 16);
int r = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
int g = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
int b = (color >> 0) & 0xFF;
```

Comment: but my color is not string. iam getting the color by using R.color.ItemColor1 so it is int

Comment: int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.white);

Answer (score 1):

Updated with ContextCompat as **getColor is Deprecated.**

```
int color = ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorAccent);
float red = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
float green = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
float blue = (color) & 0xFF;
float alpha = (color >> 24) & 0xFF;
```

Hope it will useful.

Answer (score 0):

This function converts an color value to an RGBA value.
The color value can be in the form of an integer, a string, or an array.
The RGBA color value is returned as an array of four floats.

```
public static float[] toRGBA(int color) {
    float[] rgba = new float[4];
    rgba[0] = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
    rgba[1] = (color >> 8)  & 0xFF;
    rgba[2] = (color)       & 0xFF;
    rgba[3] = (color >> 24) & 0xFF;
    return rgba;
}
```