# How to set auto inverting color of text in TextView?

Tags: android

For example, if the background was white, the text color would be black. If the BG was black, the text would be white. Blue BG, yellow text, etc.
**Update:**

```
// method in MyActivity class
void changeBackgroundColor(int newColor) {
    activityLayout.setBackgroundColor(newColor);
    int invertingColor = ColorInvertor.invert(newColor);
    someTextView.setTextColor(invertingColor);
}
```

If I call `activity.changeBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)`, then `someTextView` has to change the text color to black, i.e. `ColorInvertor.invert(Color.WHITE) == Color.BLACK`, and `ColorInvertor.invert(Color.BLACK) == Color.WHITE` etc.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a programer forum, so you are not likely to get answers on application use here. Please try [Superuser forum](http://superuser.com/) where help on application and OS use is provided.

Comment: Did you tried anything?

Comment: would give more code please

Comment: I'm programmer and I wanted to know whether there is a method that allows you to invert the text color to the background color. Thank you  for your help!

Comment: u just edit your question else it will be closed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602902/how-to-set-text-color-of-textview-in-code check this. its not for inverting u have to write code for your need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the rgb values of your color and substract them from 255 :

```
yourColor = Color.rgb(0,130,20);

invertedRed = 255 - 0;
invertedGreen = 255 - 130;
invertedBlue = 255 - 20;

text.setTextColor(Color.rgb(invertedRed,invertedGreen,invertedBlue));
```

If you want to use hex values see [How to get RGB value from hexadecimal color code in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427141/how-to-get-rgb-value-from-hexadecimal-color-code-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible just by using simple conditions:

1.Get the color

2.Check the condition

3.Set the color

To get the color:

```
TextView tv1;
tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
ColorDrawable tv1color = (ColorDrawable) tv1.getBackground();
```

If you're on Android 3.0+, you can get out the resource ID of the color:

```
int tv1colorId = tv1color.getColor();
```

To set the Color:

```
TextView tv2;
tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
tv2.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
```

Then put a condition as you want:

```
if (tv1colorID == R.color.green) {
   tv2.setBackgroundColor(color.WHITE); // As your choice color
}
```

Comment: Impossible to test all possible colors.

Comment: How, All the colors has its Hexcode, you can use the hexcode in conditions

Answer (score 0):

You can inverse a color by using those function...

```
//color
public static String getHex(int intColor) {
    String hexColor = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & intColor));
    return hexColor;
}

public static String getRGBStringfromHex(String hexColor) {
    int color = Color.parseColor(hexColor);
    int red = Color.red(color);
    int green = Color.green(color);
    int blue = Color.blue(color);
    return red + "," + green + "," + blue;
}

public static int[] getRGBStringtoRGBInt(String splits[]) {
    int list[] = new int[3];
    list[0]=Integer.parseInt(splits[0]);
    list[1]=Integer.parseInt(splits[1]);
    list[2]=Integer.parseInt(splits[2]);
    return list;
}

public static int getRGBColor(int rgb[]) {
    int color = Color.rgb(rgb[0],rgb[1],rgb[2]);
    return color;
}

public static String invertedRGBfromRGB(int rgb[]) {
    int invertedRed = 255 - rgb[0];
    int invertedGreen = 255 - rgb[1];
    int invertedBlue = 255 - rgb[2];
    return invertedRed + "," + invertedGreen + "," + invertedBlue;
}

public static int getColorFromRGBString(String color) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String splits[] = color.split(Pattern.quote(","));
    list.add(Integer.parseInt(splits[0]));
    list.add(Integer.parseInt(splits[1]));
    list.add(Integer.parseInt(splits[2]));
    return Color.rgb(list.get(0), list.get(1), list.get(2));
}
```

Ok now if you convert a int color...

```
String rgb[]=getRGBStringfromHex(getHex(colorThatWanttoInvert)).split(",");
int desireinvertedcolor=getColorFromRGBString(invertedRGBfromRGB(getRGBStringtoRGBInt(rgb)));
```

Hope this will help.